# how to read certain lines of a file that is the output of fc command with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have a text file (temp.txt) that is the output of a fc command, like this:

```
Comparando archivos test1.txt y TEST2.TXT
***** test1.txt

line1

line2

line3

etc
***** TEST2.TXT
*****
```

And i want read only the lines between the *****, i.e., line1, line2, line3, etc, so i can process them afterwards... lines are links!!!

I'm thinking in something like:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (temp.txt) do (
    if %%A not contains "*****" and is not empty (
        echo %%A
    )
)
```

But i can't figure out how to do the "not contains" and non empty conditional for the if command...

EDIT: I'm trying this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (temp.txt) do (    
    echo %%A | findstr /i /c:"http" > nul
    echo %%A:%errorlevel%
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo    %%A
    )
)
```

But i'm getting all %errorlevel%=0?_?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to show just the lines that have the `http` string, just use `findstr /i "http" temp.txt`

Comment: right!! Sorry for the question but is my first time using findstr!! Thankz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a `for` or delayed expansion:

```
SET inputFile=input.txt
type %inputfile% | findstr /vb "*****" |find /i "http:"
```

`findstr /vb` returns only lines that dont (`v`) start with (`b`) the string `*****`.

Comment: Excelent!! Thanks!

Comment: There are no lines that include `http:` that _also_ start with `*****`, so the first `| findstr /vb "*****"` is redundant...

Comment: @Aacini or just `findstr /bi "http"`. I deciced to answer the question as literal as possible for future seekers.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET inputFile=input.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (%inputFile%) DO (
    SET tempLine=%%L
    SET tempLine=!tempLine:*****=!
    IF NOT %%L==!tempLine! (
        ECHO You are looking for this line: %%L
    )
)
```

We are iterating over all lines in your text file. `SET tempLine=!tempLine:*****=!` removes `*****` from each line. Then we can simply compare the original line with the modified one. If they are equal, we know that the original line didn't contain `*****`. Otherwise, it did and you know that this line should be processed.

Comment: Great!  First comment works for the case I'm working now (all lines are links), and this works in any case. Thanks!